# [TeamCity]The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: bitbucket, teamcity

we have a TeamCity build definition with many VCS sources (bitbucket) in the one build. Once upon a time a developer committed the file with a special character in the name (e.g. `UnitTests[SpecialCharHere]packages.config`). Since that, our build doesn't work at all because of TeamCity unable to download sources for this VCS.

```
Error while applying patch: Failed to change binary file: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\51597906782d4c16\UnitTests
packages.config. C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\51597906782d4c16\UnitTests
packages.config (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

What I have found so far on the internet related to this error message are all about a blocked file by another process. Another suggestion that I've found is to delete the folder in the build agent, but it doesn't work either.
We also deleted and added VCS - nothing has changed.

Does anyone have an idea how to force TeamCity to download the latest version of the sources (because this corrupted file has been deleted already)?

Comment: I had a similar problem, not related to the file name, but for some reason my build agent was behaving as if it had two instances of the build agent installed. An uninstall of the build agent, reboot and reinstall solved the problem. Have you fixed the file name in the repository? If you have and you're trying to pull the latest build then the file name is unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: yes, the name has been fixed instantly, but the problem remains. The core reason for it is that TeamCity patches the local copy commit-by-commit. so that it cannot download certain commit from the repository... and for now i don't know how to force it to download the latest one

Comment: Might be worth [reporting it to JetBrains](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics), they're usually pretty helpful, and if it's a bug it'll get added to their backlog. Failing that, the only other thing I can think of is to edit the history to get rid of that commit, but that's obviously a pretty sucky solution.